# Ethogram plot in R with image() not working well

Tags: r, image, plot

I'm working on an ethogram with Rstudio using the image() function, but in some cases, colors do not correspond to data.

I have vectors containing the succession of 3 states, and I want to plot each state with a certain color.

The code and previous calculations are enormous, so I will just show the problematic lines.

I have a vector of 'animal states' like

```
> sub_input2$state_ind
> [1] 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1
```

And a vector containing the colors for each state (1->Red, 2->Green, 3->Blue)

```
> MWcluster.col
>[1] "#8E0939" "#005900" "#0044A4"
```

I plot with the following command:

```
>image(as.matrix(sub_input2$state_ind),col=MWcluster.col[sub_input2$state_ind],axes=FALSE)
```

And got this output
[image: There is just one color (red), instead of (red-blue-red)]

If I do not specify the `col=` parameter I got the following

```
>image(as.matrix(sub_input2$state_ind),axes=FALSE)
```

[image: Here the color changes when needed]

Surprisingly, some ethograms are plotted in this wrong way, but some others behave well, as the one I show at following.

```
> sub_input2$state_ind
> 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3

>image(as.matrix(sub_input2$state_ind), col=MWcluster.col[sub_input2$state_ind],axes=FALSE)
```

[image: The first plot is supposed to look as this one]

If I plot without specifying `col=`, I got the following

```
> image(as.matrix(sub_input2$state_ind),axes=FALSE)
```

[image]

Then, as a summary. When plotting some vectors with `image()` I got what I expect, but other vectors are not plotted properly if I specify the `col=` parameter. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the help of `image`:
`col`= *a list of colors such as that generated by `rainbow`, `heat.colors`, `topo.colors`, `terrain.colors` or similar functions.*
**Hence, the length of `col` should be equal to the number of unique values in the input matrix `z` to be plotted and not the length of the `z` matrix.**
Here are some illustrative examples that show how `image` assigns colors to `z` values.
We consider a vector `x` with values 1, 2, and 3 and a vector `col` of 3 colors:

```
x <- c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5))
cols <- c("#8E0939", "#005900", "#0044A4")
```

In the first example we pass to the `col` option of `image` only **one** of the three colors. As expected, `image` plots all the values of `x` using the specified color.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
image(z=as.matrix(x), col=col[1], axes=F)
image(z=as.matrix(x), col=col[2], axes=F)
image(z=as.matrix(x), col=col[3], axes=F)
```

[image]

In the second example we pass to the `col` option of `image` only **two** colors and change the order of values 1, 2, 3 in the `x` vector. In this case `image` maps 1 and 2 to the first element of the `col` vector and 3 to the second element.

```
windows()
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
x <- c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5))
image(z=as.matrix(x), col=col[c(1,2)], axes=F)
x <- c(rep(1,5),rep(3,5),rep(2,5))
image(z=as.matrix(x), col=col[c(1,2)], axes=F)
x <- c(rep(3,5),rep(2,5),rep(1,5))
image(z=as.matrix(x), col=col[c(1,2)], axes=F)
```

[image]

In the final example we pass to the `col` option of `image` **three** colors and change the order of 1, 2, 3 values in the `x` vector. The plots show that `image` maps value 1 to the first element of `col`, 2 to the second color and 3 to the third color.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
x <- c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5))
image(z=as.matrix(x), col=col, axes=F)
x <- c(rep(1,5),rep(3,5),rep(2,5))
image(z=as.matrix(x), col=col, axes=F)
x <- c(rep(3,5),rep(2,5),rep(1,5))
image(z=as.matrix(x), col=col, axes=F)
```

[image]

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, I've changed:

`image(as.matrix(sub_input2$state_ind), col=col[sub_input2$state_ind], axes=FALSE)`

to

`image(z=as.matrix(sub_input2$state_ind), col=col,axes=FALSE)`

and some things start working well, at least all state changes are plotted, but some are assigned wrong colors.
When my vector contains states (1,3) or (1,2,3) works well, but when they contain (1,2) or (2,3), some colors 'fail' as you explained. At least now I know why is this happening and I can make a conditional on this to make all work properly. 

Really, thanks!

Comment: @JaviChinaski Please, could you consider to upvote my answer? Thank you.